# Where does ANT output compiler errors?

Tags: java, cordova, ant

I have been working on a PhoneGap application and compiling through the console using ANT. I am getting a java error that says I can see the details in the compiler error output. However... I am at a loss as to where the output is located.

Is there actually an output file that I can view? I have tried using the "-d" for debug mode without any additional help.

Thanks.

**UPDATE (Console Output):**

> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\android-sdk\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: The following error occurred while e
>   xecuting this line:
>   C:\android-sdk\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following error occurred while e
>   xecuting this line:
>   C:\android-sdk\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler err
>   or output for details.

Comment: If you are invoking ant in a console window, the output should be in the console window.

Comment: Does not appear to be. (Updating Question with what I am seeing)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in several ways, the output typically goes to your console so you can

```
ant task > output.log
```

Then tail the log. Or maybe better yet, you can use the logfile option when you execute ant

```
-logfile <file>        use given file for log
```

Comment: Will that show the details or that just going to replicate what I am seeing already in the console?

Comment: Sorry, that will show the same as console.  I generally see compile errors as part of the ant output though, you don't?  Are you just calling ant straight from the command line?

Comment: I calling it through phonegap build

Comment: my guess is that phonegap is setting some props or redirecting output.  Sorry I could not be of more help. :(

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question of

> Where does ANT output compiler errors?

is that ant outputs compiler errors to either standard out (STDOUT) or standard error (STDERR) streams.

I can't tell you what those point to.  Generally, if invoking from a shell, STDOUT and STDERR go to the console window.  If you see regular output, but not the error, that suggests it is being redirected to somewhere else.

I am curious if you are actually executing `ant` directly, or some sort of wrapper / tool that turns around and executes ant.  If the latter, the wrapper may be altering where output goes.